# Flexbox Scroll bar to the centre

Tags: html, css, mudblazor

Can we position the scroll bar of flex box to the centre of the screen ?

At present by following the below code

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYmcEIQgRenmtTnS

I am getting UI like  below  with scroll bar on bottom of the container DIV
[image: Scroll bar on bottom of the screen]

Instead Can we make the position or style of scrolling to something like this with help of html /css

[image]

Comment: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/XwbNwX here it is

Comment: @LeviD. impressive example, without any JS, very clean thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is call slider. Try google from that keyword and you'll be able to create it

Comment: Slider is a control where we can show one div or image at a time For example Red or Blue at a time . But the  UX i am trying is something similar to a Pricing table basically comparing a list of values or properties Sometimes the no of items to compare is a big list and then presence of scroll bar (both vertical and horizontal ) is necessary  and Ideally need to place the horizontal scroll bar to the centre as in the image

Comment: OK so the above cmt from Levi D. should solved it. You just need to add the arrow on top of everything codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/XwbNwX

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use Carousel of MudBlazor. The Components are easy to use and don't require a lot of css to modify.

[Documentation](https://mudblazor.com/components/carousel)
[Example in TryMudBlazor](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GYQmaywApLcqcQWc)

For further usages check out the documentation, there are plenty examples on this topic.

Comment: Carousels/ Slider are controls  where we can show one div or image at a time For example Red or Blue at a time . But the UX i am trying is something similar to a Pricing table which  basically comparing a list of values or properties Sometimes the no of items to compare is a big list and then presence of scroll bar (both vertical and horizontal ) is necessary and Ideally need to place the horizontal scroll bar to the centre as in the image